# replacing nested backreferences in regular expression

Tags: regex, grep, nested, pcre

I've extracted a column from an Excel spreadsheet where some cells contain multiple rows, some don't. The multi-row cells are delimited by quote marks. I want to replace the returns in those multi-row cells with ", ". So my file looks something like this:

```
"Alpha
 Beta
 Gamma"
 123
 456
"Apple
 Banana
 Cherry"
 789
 this is a single-line cell
```

My goal is

```
 Alpha, Beta, Gamma
 123
 456
 Apple, Banana, Cherry
 789
 this is a single-line cell
```

I can write a pattern that captures those multi-line cells using a nested pattern, but I don't know how to "reach inside" to get at the backreference.

```
"(([^"]+)\n)+([^"]+)"
```

Comment: There are no nested backreferences. Regex does not work like that, the repeated capturing group only keeps the last occurrence matched during the last iteration.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed '/^"/{:a; /"$/bb; N; ba; :b; s/\n//g}' file
"Alpha Beta Gamma"
 123
 456
"Apple Banana Cherry"
 789
 this is a single-line cell
```

#### How it works

- `/^"/{...}`

  For any lines that begins with `"`, the commands in curly braces will be performed.
- `:a`

  This creates a label `a`.
- `/"$/bb`

  If the current pattern space ends with a `"`, then branch to label `b`.
- `N`

  Read a new line into the pattern space.
- `ba`

  Branch back to label `a`.
- `:b`

  This defines label `b`.
- `s/\n//g`

  Remove any newline characters from the pattern space.

Comment: Thanks. I had to change the substitution to s/\n/, /g, but I appreciate the step-by-step. This just reinforces for me that I need to break down and learn sed or awk.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='"[^"]+"|[^"\n]+' '$0=RT{gsub(/^\s+|\s+$|"/,""); gsub(/\n/,","); print}' file
Alpha, Beta, Gamma
123
456
Apple, Banana, Cherry
789
this is a single-line cell
```